# "Get through to sb" and "Get (a)hold of sb"

Tags: idioms

I have looked up many definitions in various dictionaries, but still I can't tell these two similar expressions apart. What is the difference betwen the two idioms **"get through to sb"** and **"get (a)hold of sb"** when it comes to phone conversations?
I would be appreciative if you could provide me with some distinctive examples so that I could figure out how they differ!

Answer (score 1):

"Get through to" implies a deeper level of interaction than "get (a)hold of".

If you are trying to communicate with someone, first you have to "get (a)hold of" the person. In other words, you have to find him, present yourself, and make an initial contact with him. This could either be in person or by phone or other electronic means. Probably not by postal mail, though, since if you merely sent him a letter, you would not know if he received it. Getting (a)hold of implies mutual acknowledgement.

The next step in a communication (after you have gotten (a)hold of the "target" individual) is "getting through to" him. You must give him your message. Again, it could be spoken in person or by phone, or in writing, even in this case by postal mail. When the target receives *and understands* your message, then, and only then, have you really "gotten through to" him.

Please note that for "getting through to", it is absolutely necessary that the person understands the message you are trying to give him. It often happens that you give someone a message, but the person doesn't understand it. If he hears it but doesn't "get" it, then we say something like:

"I keep explaining it, but I can't seem to **get through to** him.

It is also possible that you *think* he understands, but in reality he doesn't. In that case you have not "gotten through to" him, even though you *think* you have.

Comment: In British English (i don't know about other dialects) successfully contacting someone by phone could equally well be described as "getting hold" of them, or "getting through" to them. The second meaning is separate from anything to do with making a stubborn or stupid person understand something.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey The only meaning given in CALDT, OALD, Collins, Macmillan, and Longman is "to succeed in making someone understand something." It's the American dictionaries (MW, AHD) which provide the second meaning of "succeed in making a telephone call."

Comment: Nevertheless, we say it in Britain, and have done so all my life.

Comment: @choster what is the AmE common take on these idiom? Could you please explain it here?

Comment: In the US, we do sometimes use "getting through to someone" when we mean "contacting them" (usually by phone and with some difficulty.): "Perkins is hiking the Appalachian Trail this summer, but I was finally able to get through to him on Friday, and he gave his approval." That was not the meaning that I thought of at first, but it isn't uncommon. I think the source of this idiom is the old practice of telephone operators patching connections together on the plug board: ... "Operator, put me **through to** the police, and please hurry!"